# Reading from an input file and storing words into an array

Tags: c, string, io, strtok

The end goal is to output a text file where repeating words are encoded as single digits instead. The current problem I'm having is reading words and storing them into an array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_CODE 120
void main() {
    FILE *inputfile = fopen("input.txt","rw");
    char buffer[128];
    char *token;
    char *words[MAX_CODE];
    int i = 0;
    while(fgets(buffer, 128, inputfile)){
        token = strtok(buffer," ");
        printf("Token %d was %s",i,token);
        while(token != NULL) {
            words[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
            strcpy(words[i], token);
            i++;
            token = strtok(buffer," ");
        }
    }
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) printf("%d\n%s\n",i,words[i]);
printf("End");
}
```

What I get is segmentation fault errors, or nothing. What I want is for words to be an array of strings. I'm allocating memory for each string, so where am I going wrong?

Comment: What line is the seg fault on? Have you tried to figure out where the problem is? What does your input look like?

Comment: Try walking the code with the debugger. You'll see where it dies.

Comment: Is there a debugger built into gcc? I'm running from the command line.

Comment: My input is a txt file in the same directory with this as its contents: three words repeating three words repeating three

Comment: `token = strtok(buffer," ");` may be `NULL`, next line `printf("Token %d was %s",i,token);`  will crash. Add check for `(token != NULL) ` or handle it with `token ? token : "NULL"`

Comment: Nice catch, however catching that changes nothing.Still get no output back to the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second call to `strtok` should pass `NULL` for the first argument. Otherwise, `strtok` will parse the first token over and over again.

```
    token = strtok(buffer," ");
    printf("Token %d was %s\n",i,token);
    while(i < MAX_CODE && token != NULL) {
        words[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);
        strcpy(words[i], token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
```

The check against `MAX_CODE` is for the safety's sake, in case you ever increase the size of your `buffer` or reduce the value of `MAX_CODE`. In your current code, the maximum number of space delimited tokens you can hold in a 128 byte buffer is 64.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

> - If `str != NULL`, the call is treated as the first call to `strtok` for this particular string. ...
> - If `str == NULL`, the call is treated as a subsequent calls to `strtok`: the function continues from where it left in previous invocation. ...